# Angular 2 Jasmine wait for timeout before continuing

Tags: angular, asynchronous, jasmine, angular2-testing

In my code I have a method that returns a part object, however it returns the object inside a `setTimeout` method. When I attempt to test this I'm running into the issue that the test does not wait until the timeout has completed before it evaluates the response for the method. How can I go about telling the test to wait for the timeout to complete before it checks the expectation?

As you can see the `getIntersection` method returns this.part inside of a timeout.

```
public getIntersection(payload: DropPayload): Part {
  let rect: ClientRect = this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (rect.left < payload.event.pageX && rect.right > payload.event.pageX && rect.top < payload.event.pageY && rect.bottom > payload.event.pageY) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.changeRef.detectChanges();
      return this.part;
    });
  }
  return null;
}
```

Here's a few things I've tried based on researching this issue, none of them work:

1:

```
it('return the part if the payload coordinates are inside the bounding box', async((done) => {
  partInstance.part = Clone.create(mockPart);
  let result: any = partInstance.getIntersection(mockPayload);
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(result).toEqual(mockPart);
    done();
  });
}));
```

2:

```
it('return the part if the payload coordinates are inside the bounding box', async(() => {
  partInstance.part = Clone.create(mockPart);
  let result: any = partInstance.getIntersection(mockPayload);
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(result).toEqual(mockPart);
  });
}));
```

3: (this one throws errors that `runs` isn't defined. I believe this is an Angular 1 solution)

```
it('return the part if the payload coordinates are inside the bounding box', () => {
  let done: boolean = false;
  let result: any;
  runs(() => {
    partInstance.part = Clone.create(mockPart);
    result = partInstance.getIntersection(mockPayload);
    setTimeout(() => {
      done = true;
    });
  });
  waitsFor(() => {
    return done;
  });
  runs(() => {
      expect(result).toEqual(mockPart);
  });
});
```

4:

```
it('return the part if the payload coordinates are inside the bounding box', () => {
  partInstance.part = Clone.create(mockPart);
  let result: any = partInstance.getIntersection(mockPayload);
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(result).toEqual(mockPart);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your logic

```
public getIntersection(payload: DropPayload): Part {
  let rect: ClientRect = this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  if (rect.left < payload.event.pageX && rect.right > payload.event.pageX && rect.top < payload.event.pageY && rect.bottom > payload.event.pageY) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.changeRef.detectChanges();
      return this.part;
    });
  }
  return null;
}
```

Two things:

1. The `setTimeout` happens asynchronously. But the return in the main function happens synchronously. The return value will always be null
2. Returning in the callback of the `setTimeout` doesn't do what you think it does, i.e magically make the return value something else. What you return in the callback *is not* what is the return value for the main function.

You need to restructure your code, maybe to use promises. Have the method return a promise

```
public getIntersection(payload: DropPayload): Promise<Part> {
  let rect: ClientRect = this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.changeRef.detectChanges();
      resolve(this.part);
    })
  })
}
```

I have no idea what the logic behind your method is for, so I just left it out. But you will probably need to incorporate it back somehow.

Then you can call the function like

```
getIntersection().then(part => {
  expect(...)
})
```

Using your attempt with the Angular `async` should work for this.